# How to make specific elements of a cell equal to zero?

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell

I have a 41 * 41 cell array, and I would like to make the values greater than 0.5 equal to zeros in Matlab, while keeping the rest of the values without any changes. Is it possible to work directly on the cell, or do we need to convert it to a matrix first?

## My try

```
AAA = cell2mat( BBB );
for i = 1: length(AAA)
    for j = 1 : i
        if AAA(i,j) > 0.5
            AAA(i,i) = 0;
        else
            cc = AAA(i,j);
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Please post a mininal example. What is `BBB`?

Comment: Why do you use `AAA(i,i) = 0;` rather than `AAA(i,j) = 0;`? The former will only change the elements on the diagonal - not the elements larger than 0.5 - is this what you want?

Comment: @LuisMendo BBB is a cell

Comment: @magnesium I forgot sir.

Comment: What @LuisMendo is asking is provide a concrete example (with code) for what `BBB` is. For example, is `BBB = num2cell(rand(41));` representative of what is actually in your cell array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since logical indexing is not supported for operands of type 'cell', you have to convert to matrix first. Use logical indexing on the matrix and convert back to cell. Assuming BBB is like `BBB = num2cell(rand(41))`, then

```
AAA = cell2mat(BBB);
AAA(AAA > 0.5) = 0;
BBB = num2cell(AAA)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one-liner to avoid converting the cell array to a matrix and then back to a cell array by calling [`cell2mat`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html) and [`num2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html)/[`mat2cell`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mat2cell.html).

Assuming an example cell array like this:

```
BBB = num2cell(rand(41));
```

Then use [`cellfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) to apply a function to each cell:

```
CCC = cellfun(@(x)x.*(x<=0.5),BBB,'UniformOutput',false);
```

This will return a cell array, `CCC`, the same size as the input, `BBB`.

Comment: Note, however, that less code and not converting to a matrix and back first is not necessarily faster. In many cases the `num2cell` with logical indexing and a good single `for` loop implementation will be faster. This is likely due to the function call overhead inherent in `cellfun`. However, for a simple 41-by-41 cell array the computation time won't add up to much unless you're doing hundreds of times.